# Reading data from SQLite3 database and using them

Tags: database, python-2.7, sqlite

To start off, I really don't know if this have been answered before.

I looked all over but still couldn't find an example..

And I'm new to SQLite3 and obviously I would run into these kind of problems.

Basically what I'm doing is creating a SQLite3 database save as : "Data.dll".

And I've created a table and inserted some data in there..

Now, basically what I want to do is like ask the user a question, and the user has to input a number AND a "Key".

When inputted I want to check if it's valid.

For example,

DATA #1 :

NUMBERID : 30138

KEY: KeyUser1

DATA #2 :

NUMBERID : 1144

KEY : key2

If those were both inputted (Like 30138, and KeyUser1. not like 30138 and key2)  then they can keep going, otherwise, It would say that the NUMBER ID and "KEY" Do not match.

So how can I do that?

I'm new to SQLite3 and so I'm still a newbie...

Any help is appreciated.

My Code:

```
import sqlite3
dbase = sqlite3.connect("Data.dll")
print "DataBase Opened : Success."
dbase.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Keys(
  NUMBERID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  VAILD TEXT NOT NULL)""")

print "DataBase Table : Success"

def insert_record(NUMBERID,VAILD):
    dbase.execute(""" INSERT INTO Keys (NUMBERID,VAILD)
 VALUES(?,?)""", (NUMBERID,VAILD))
    dbase.commit()

#insert_record(1144, 'key2') # If needed to insert soemthing...

print "DataBase Insert : Success."

def read_Data():
    data = dbase.execute(""" SELECT NUMBERID,VAILD FROM Keys """)
    for record in data:
        NUMBER_ID = str(record[0])
        VAILD_KEY = str (record [1])
        print NUMBER_ID # Check
        print VAILD_KEY # Check


read_Data()

NUMBER_ENTER = input ("Enter NUMBER ID : ")
VAILD_ENTER = raw_input ("Enter KEY : ")
if NUMBER_ENTER in  NUMBER_ID:
    print "1" # If its at least correct print this
    ... 
else:
    print "2" # wrong
    ...
if VAILD_ENTER in VAILD_KEY:
    print "a" # if its at least correct , print this.
    ...
else:
    print "z" # wrong
    ...
dbase.close()
print "DataBase Closed : Success."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
def check(number, key):                                                                                                                                                                                     
    data = dbase.execute("select 1 from keys where NUMBERID = ? AND VAILD = ?",     (number, key)).fetchone()                                                                                                   
    return data                                                                                                                                                                                             

NUMBER_ENTER = input("Enter NUMBER ID : ")                                                                                                                                                                  
VAILD_ENTER = raw_input("Enter KEY : ")                                                                                                                                                                     

if check(NUMBER_ENTER, VAILD_ENTER):                                                                                                                                                                        
    print 1                                                                                                                                                                                                 
else:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    print 2
```

where you check if there is a row with the NUMBERID, VAILD